# Not Load Images from Web in my application

Tags: android, android-imageview, image-loading, android-image

Hello i use [Loading Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012) for Loading Images. But my images are not load. I work on that and develop one Demo program that is as follows.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image))
            .execute("http://www.morroccomethod.com/components/com_virtuemart/shop_image/category/resized/Raw_Conditioner_500835f701532_175x175.jpg");
}

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = new ProgressDialog(ImageLoadExampleActivity.this);
        pd.show();
    }

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        pd.dismiss();

    }
}
```

It does not work. But if i change URL of image at that time image is loaded successfully. My question is this perticular url is not loaded in my android application. Please help me to find this. I spend one days on this. Thanks in advance.

-Hardik

Comment: What is the URL that works successfully?

Comment: http://www.morroccomethod.com/components/com_virtuemart/shop_image/category/resized/Natural_Shampoo_500835bcdd5b6_175x175.jpg  @paritybit

Comment: http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/850960042/elandroidelibre-logo_300x300_normal.jpg  @paritybit

Comment: so it works when bottle is placed upside-down :) anyway try to give the name of the successful image to the problematic image, in order to see if the problem is related to the image file itself.

Comment: @paritybit i think problem in image i replace most of url images with other but my urls does not display images. i am stuck on this dude.

Comment: you've said 'https://www.morroccomethod.com/components/com_virtuemart/shop_image/category/resized/Natural_Shampoo_500835bcdd5b6_175x175.jpg' works but 'http://www.morroccomethod.com/components/com_virtuemart/shop_image/category/resized/Raw_Conditioner_500835f701532_175x175.jpg' does not, didn't you?

Comment: this means it is not about URL, but can be related to image file or file name.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/sZEp7ZS4 @paritybit

Comment: maybe your android device cannot access moroccomethod.com, try browsing the images from your device's browser to see if this is the case. if so it may be related to DNS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending 2 days i finally come here to give answer on my own question. The main problem is of file names. I change file names and file location of files and my issue is solve. Thanks all which give me idea.

**One also thing which i come to know that i modify my http:// with https://**

Comment: glad you sorted it - but if you have the issue again with HTTP => HTTPS my solution should help you

Comment: @hardikjoshi - I did I amended my answer with the solution to handle http=>https that appeared to be causing your loading issue.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following to get images from an endpoint

```
URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
InputStream content = (InputStream)url.getContent();
Drawable image = Drawable.createFromStream(content , "src");
```

perhaps you can adapt this

---

Okay I downloaded the sample and looked at URLs - the issue appears to be the HTTP => HTTPS redirection (I mentioned that I had to change them in my sample - I also notice my browser was forced to switch to https when I tried to load your images from the supplied strings). The sample does not appear to handle that correctly however if I alter ImageLoader.getBitmap to this then it does

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
{
    File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

    //from SD cache
    Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
    if(b!=null)
        return b;

    //from web
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap=null;

        HttpURLConnection conn;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        int rc = -1;
        do {
            conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            rc = conn.getResponseCode();
            imageUrl = conn.getURL();
        } while (rc == -1); // hmmm - perhaps a http => https

        InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
       return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi @shaun i try with most of codes dude but still i m facing problem.

Comment: okay, I use the above to get twitter avatars and have had no issues with it.

Comment: can you please help me to find this.

Comment: I replaced my URLs with yours (https rather than http though) and using the above code the I get the images, it does take some time though (2-3 seconds).

Comment: i use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012 for list of products in which i replace my URLs it not work dude. i am so stuck with this.

Comment: Have you tried replacing his image collection with yours in the sample?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15549/discussion-between-hardik-joshi-and-shaun-wilde)

Answer (score 1):

```
public String loadImageFromWebOperations(String url, String path) {
    try {
        is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        System.out.println(path);
        File f = new File(path);
        f.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        try {
            byte[] b = new byte[100];
            int l = 0;
            while ((l = is.read(b)) != -1)
            fos.write(b, 0, l);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error in creating file", "", e);
        }
        Log.e("created file path is :", "" + f.getAbsolutePath());
        return f.getAbsolutePath();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exc=" + e);
        return null;
    }
}

If any issue let me know...
```